# initramfs Unable Mount Root File System

Tags: linux-kernel, filesystems, root, mount, panic

I compiled Linux kernel with cpio filesystem that includes busybox.

**Specs**

- Linux 4.8
- Busybox 12.5.1
- toolchain GNU Binutils
- GCC whose target is i486-linux-uclibc
- uCLibc library that's compiled with this toolchain.

Linux kernel's configure is i386_defconfig and some changes. Toolchain's compiler prefix specified, hostname, kernel compression mode is XZ, support initramfs only XZ enabled, optimize for size enabled in Linux kernel's conifgure.

I compiled Linux kernel successfully.

After I tested initramfs with QEMU 2.5.0. These parameters are `qemu-system-i386 -m 256 -kernel bzImage -display curses`.

BUt, Linux kernel given error. This error is listed below:

```
[    3.745110]  00000000 00000086 cf8adef8 c12276e0 cf8adf00 cf0ae000 cf8adf10 c
10cb4c6
[    3.745110]  cf0ae000 cf8adf44 cf0ae000 cffc15c0 cf8adf70 c19aaef3 c17e967e c
f8adf44
[    3.745110]  c17e962d c17e95fa 00000000 cf8adf44 fffffffa cf0ae15a c17e96e2 0
0000000
[    3.745110] Call Trace:
[    3.745110]  [<c12276e0>] dump_stack+0x47/0x5b
[    3.745110]  [<c10cb4c6>] panic+0x8f/0x1ae
[    3.745110]  [<c19aaef3>] mount_block_root+0x12c/0x1b9
[    3.745110]  [<c1002930>] ? x86_pmu_hw_config+0x80/0x1a6
[    3.745110]  [<c19ab146>] mount_root+0x10e/0x115
[    3.745110]  [<c110ea97>] ? SyS_unlink+0x10/0x12
[    3.745110]  [<c19ab263>] prepare_namespace+0x116/0x147
[    3.745110]  [<c19aac38>] kernel_init_freeable+0x191/0x1a3
[    3.745110]  [<c165307a>] kernel_init+0x8/0xd0
[    3.745110]  [<c16561a2>] ret_from_kernel_thread+0xe/0x24
[    3.745110]  [<c1653072>] ? rest_init+0x5f/0x5f
[    3.745110] Kernel Offset: disabled
[    3.745110] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs
 on unknown-block(0,0)
```

How can I solve this problem?

**Edit:** I used kernel parameter `rootfstype=ramfs` and kernel gave another error:

```
[    4.212083]  00000000 00000086 cf89bf88 c121c501 cf8a0000 c1906560 cf89bfa0 c
10c5bdf
[    4.212083]  c1906560 cf8a0000 c1906560 cfdd3980 cf89bfac c1645fe3 c17db667 c
18ddf04
[    4.212083]  c1649022 c1645f17 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 0
0000000
[    4.212083] Call Trace:
[    4.212083]  [<c121c501>] dump_stack+0x47/0x5b
[    4.212083]  [<c10c5bdf>] panic+0x8f/0x1ae
[    4.212083]  [<c1645fe3>] kernel_init+0xcc/0xd0
[    4.212083]  [<c1649022>] ret_from_kernel_thread+0xe/0x24
[    4.212083]  [<c1645f17>] ? rest_init+0x5f/0x5f
[    4.212083] Kernel Offset: disabled
[    4.212083] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: No working init found.  Try
passing init= option to kernel. See Linux Documentation/init.txt for guidance.
```

How can linux kernel detect init? Thanks for replies.

Comment: *"How can I solve this problem?"* -- What did you build?  What's the kernel command line?  An initramfs does not have to be mounted.  If the cpio archive is properly appended to the kernel image, then the kernel will always use the initramfs, and never tries to look for or mount a rootfs.

Comment: I know bzImage may not need command line. Just `rootfstype=ramfs` command is worked, but I gave another error that is next step.

Comment: Also added `rdinit=/sbin/init` parameter, it works.